# Flutter nested lists size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a vertical list where each item is an images horizontal list.

The images size is set in the Image widget but I get a black screen if I don't set an external Container with a height value.

My question is, how can I set a Widget hight to wrap the child widgets so I don't need to set the external container height?

This is my code:

```
         return ListView.builder( //External vertical list
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemBuilder: (context, outerIndex) {
          print(
              "Outer ListView.builder: building item $outerIndex of ${snapshot.data.length} items");
          return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                height: 300, //When I remove Container and height value, I get black screen
                child: ListView.builder( //Internal horizontal list
                    itemCount: snapshot.data[outerIndex].items.length,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, mediaIndex) {
                      print("Inner ListView.builder: mediaItem $mediaIndex");
                      return Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                        child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                          height: 300,
                          width: 160,
                          placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                          image: TmdbService.buildImageUrl(snapshot.data[outerIndex].items[mediaIndex].poster_path),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: is something like SizedBox (https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) suitable for you? Also worth looking at FittedBox

Comment: Where should I place FittedBox in the hierarchy? 
SizedBox is also required height value no?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `height: 300,` indeed paints nothing, but it also threw an exception:

```dart
I/flutter (12081): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (12081): 'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1598 pos 16:
I/flutter (12081): 'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true.
```

So you can play around with [BoxConstraints](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/BoxConstraints-class.html) and other boxes as i wrote in the comment, but as i understand, what you really want is not to set the size twice. So why not to remove then `width` and `hegiht` from the `FadeInImage` and set them for the Container? And since you already have set `fit: BoxFit.fill` the image will just fill all available container's space.
So the following works for me:

```dart
return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        //External vertical list
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemBuilder: (context, outerIndex) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                height:300,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    //Internal horizontal list
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, mediaIndex) {
                      print("Inner ListView.builder: mediaItem $mediaIndex");
                      return Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                        child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                          placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                          image:
                              "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8a/ad/dc/8aaddc2ab4cfd6a0b17f82e04ed4800d.png",
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I can take the image size out of the image as you suggest,
but what would I do if tomorrow instead of just an image, I will have some custom widget which contains an image, and a title or bottom text under it, in this case, How can I tell the size of the parent container? What I want is to set the child (Image + and more..)  size internally and that any parent will wrap it.
I've tried to put the internal List in a Column so I can set its size with attributes but it didn't helped. Also The use with Expanded didn't worked.